# Django Rest Framework, Allow: POST not being set in generic view

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have a DRF generic view that inherits `CreateModelMixin`, but the `Allow` header does not include `POST`:

```
class OrdersView(CreateModelMixin, ListModelMixin, GenericAPIView):

    filter_backends = (DjangoFilterBackend, OrderingFilter)
    filter_fields = ('product', 'team', 'buy', 'open')
    queryset = Order.objects.all()
    serializer_class = OrderListSerializer

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.list(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.create(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

A request to the url doesn't include `POST` in the `Allow` header:

```
# OPTIONS /orders/

HTTP 200 OK
Allow: GET, HEAD, OPTIONS
Content-Type: application/json
Vary: Accept

{
    "name": "Orders",
    "description": "",
    "renders": [
        "application/json",
        "text/html"
    ],
    "parses": [
        "application/json",
        "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
        "multipart/form-data"
    ]
}
```

The view does process `POST` requests though.  I would like the `Allow` header to be accurate though.

Comment: Your code seems fine, I couldn't reproduce the behaviour. Can you make it happen?

Answer (score 0):

You will want to ensure you have enough permissions to use the POST action. DRF will not show it in OPTIONS if the request doesn't have the permission to use it.

Comment: There are no permissions filters set on the view (e.g., `permission_classes = (...,)`, this is unset and there are no defaults set)